# defaultMethodEndpointAdapter bean creation error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to follow te guide of spring-boot in order to have a SOAP server running. The problem is It is throwing this error:

```
2016-09-19 09:43:39.797  WARN 8668 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultMethodEndpointAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/ws/config/annotation/DelegatingWsConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter]: Factory method 'defaultMethodEndpointAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.setCustomMethodArgumentResolvers(Ljava/util/List;)V
```

My ws config beans file is:

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
    servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
}

@Bean(name = "expedientes")
public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema expedienteSchema) {
    DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
    wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("ExpedientesPort");
    wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws");
    wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://localhost/ws");
    wsdl11Definition.setSchema(expedienteSchema);
    return wsdl11Definition;
}

@Bean
public XsdSchema expedienteSchema() {
    return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("Expedientes.xsd"));
}
}
```

It is supposed to autoconfig the rest so I can't understand this error.

I surfed the entire site for some related errors but nothing helped me.
Any tip please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.setCustomMethodArgumentResolvers(Ljava/util/List;)V
```

Class"DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter" is part of spring-ws-core jar file. Method "DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter.setCustomMethodArgumentResolvers(List customMethodArgumentResolvers)" is available since spring-ws-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar. Following are the dependencies needed for WS project with Spring Boot 1.4.0 , as per spring guide https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/ and it will download latest spring-ws-core-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar. Please check the dependencies and versions you are using in pom.xml.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-ws</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```